# Check macro in Access 2010

Tags: vba, ms-access

Im trying to fix old MS Access file and i have to change popup menu, called by right click. Ive try to find some code in VBA, but i found there only the name of Macro which insert text from popup to form.
When I go to Macro menu i only found name of this macro, but cant change it.

What I should do to see where macro catch text data?

Comment: Welcome to SO. The macro code should be in a module. Have you checked with VBA editor?

Comment: Yes, I cheked, but I found only function, which catch data with SQL command, but I can`t find this table.

Comment: If you have the table, then you got the source. Maybe is it hidden?

Comment: Yes, it was hidden! Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

OP discovered the name of the table in the SQL sentence, but was not able to locate it. This was because it was hidden.

To hide/unhide elements in the Nav Pane, you can read:

> **[View and manage objects by using the Navigation Pane](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/view-and-manage-objects-by-using-the-navigation-pane-274dfc5a-281b-472b-94e2-ef931c5cc590#__toc309049965)**